# jQuery ajax call in php while loop only returns first id

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on wordpress plugin that updates stock prices every few seconds. I display the stock prices in html table, that is executed in php loop, which grabs stocks as wordpress posts. In my code I need the title of the post, to call the function that grabs the specific stock price.

```
<?php  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   if ($query->have_posts()) :
     $i = 1;
   while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>

<td class="name"><?php the_title(); ?></td>
<td class="price" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"></td>
```

I would like to pass the id of the specific stock post to jQuery ajax function.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
   setInterval(callMe, 5000);
});

function callMe(){
  var id = $('.price').attr("id");
  var titleInput = jQuery('#' + id).attr("value");

  $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {
              action: 'myaction',
              post_title: titleInput
         },
         success: function(response){
                    $('#' + id).html(response);
     }
 });
}
```

This is only returning first id, and is then also passing only first post title, but not the others.

Is the problem only in how I call the id? I was playing with how I call the var id, but couldn't make it work.

```
var id = $('.price').attr("id");
```

Please help if you have some suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: how many instances of the class `.price` have you got?  You're going to have to loop through them but this may inundate the server with requests

Comment: I have only about 20 stocks and their prices, which means 20 wordpress posts. Is it what you meant? I know it could get heavy for server, but at the moment I would like to get this to work. In the future I will recode the whole thing.

Comment: Yeah man, thats the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.price')` returns a collection and while there are some functions (like `.css()`) that operate directly on them, `.attr()` only operates on individual elements, so it's only returning the value of the first one:

```js
console.log($('.price').length)
console.log($('.price').attr('id'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price" id="id1" value="value1"></div>
<div class="price" id="id2" value="value2"></div>
```

You have to call your function for each individual element:

```
function callMe() {
  $('.price').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var titleInput = $(this).attr("value");

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        action: 'myaction',
        post_title: titleInput
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $('#' + id).html(response);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working like charm. I am just starting out with wordpress development and I was stuck here for few days and couldn't make this to work. Thank you.